# NServiceBus 5.0 Object reference not set to an instance of an object at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueuesCreator.Install

Tags: nservicebus

Might this be related to:
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2561?

I'm using nservicebus 5.0.3 and azurestorage queues.

I'm getting a:

```
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

When starting up after the code goes through the endpointconfig successfully - here's the stacktrace.

```
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueuesCreator.Install(String identity, Configure config)
   at NServiceBus.Features.InstallationSupport.Starter.Run(Configure config)
   at NServiceBus.Configure.<Initialize>b__8(IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete o)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize()
   at NServiceBus.Bus.Create(BusConfiguration configuration)
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1 moreConfiguration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 121
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 70
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\WindowsHost.cs:line 30
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Main>b__6(WindowsHost service) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.cs:line 80
   at Topshelf.Internal.ControllerDelegates`1.StartActionObject(Object obj) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ControllerDelegates.cs:line 18
   at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<set_StartAction>b__1(TService service) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper.cs:line 65
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.<.cctor>b__1(ServiceController`1 sc) in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:line 35
   at Magnum.StateMachine.LambdaAction`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter) in :line 0
```

Here's my endpoint config:

```
    void IConfigureThisEndpoint.Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var container = BuildContainer();
        configuration.EndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusQueueName"]);
        configuration.UseTransport<AzureStorageQueueTransport>();
        configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
        configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>();
    }

    private IContainer BuildContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var domainAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(domainAssemblies);
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Comment: Is your .config file has the right credential for Azure storage account?

Comment: Good guess - I tried that though and it's correct.

Comment: One more thing, you're using Azure transport and RavenDB. Both would need to specify NServiceBus/Transport connection string. I have tried w/o RavenDB and code worked. If you could share your repro, would be easier to look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sean - checked into that. I ended up downgrading from 5.0.3 to 5.0.0 and that resolved the issue

Comment: @HugoForte this is not related to https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2561, how can we replicate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading from 5.03 to 5.0 and that solved the issue.

Comment: Hi Hugo, technically you shouldn't downgrade. Do you mind to open an issue on GitHub at github.com/Particular/nservicebus/issues? Thank you.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be related to https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2561